# Hold credit card numbers, bank account pins etc online accessible all the time

Tags: security, dropbox

How can I hold my credit card numbers, bank account pins and other sensitive data online so it can be accessed all the time? I have so many things that I can't simply remember them/carry with me all the time but I need to often.

How can I store the secured/encrypted (dropbox somehow maybe) online so that I can access them with super-master password for an example? Or what would be the best practice to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/), along with letting you store passwords it also lets you store credit card profiles and secure notes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to login through all sorts of computers which might not be very secure, I think that would be a really bad idea.
If you still insist on doing so, then you could you LastPass or KeePass to store your passwords, and then just upload the file somewhere comfortable for you (like Dropbox you've mentioned).

Comment: Just remember that dropbox is not encrypted, so you would want to do that before putting it on there.

Comment: How can I use my android phone for an example to get my data from LastPass / Keepass?

Comment: There is no need to encrypt files coming from LastPass and KeePass - They're already encrypted.
and there are specific versions meant for Android (though I haven't tried them):
https://www.dropbox.com/android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastpass.lpandroid

Answer (score 0):

KeePassDroid is in the Android store and it's (encrypted) data file can be backed-up to other places, and can be read by PC versions of KeePass.

Or buy a deck of cards, use [Pontifex/Solitaire](http://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html) and post the cryptotext on your Facebook/Twitter/Google+ homepages ;-)